# How to see SQL 2008 Locks and Blocked Tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, timeout, locking, deadlock

During the ASP.NET execution of my app, it seems SQL 2008 Express holds some lock, and I get

> ```
> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
> ```
>
> the operation or the server is not
>   responding

Maybe some of my query is not optimized. Visual Studio crashes with:

> ```
> Microsoft Visual Studio may be unstable now. It is recommended that
> ```
>
> you save all files and exit.

I need to see what query is blocking my tables, but I have the Express version. How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: try to execute my answer

Answer (score 12):

You can query against the `sys.dm_tran_locks` dynamic view to obtain this information. Go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx) on MSDN to lean more.

Comment: can I view the query that is blocking?

Answer (score 11):

```
exec sp_lock
```

and

```
exec sp_who2
```

Answer (score 5):

`sp_who2` is a newer version of `sp_who`

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is execute this

```
sp_who
```

tells you everything you need to know.